# Extract text between two symbols (PS-Pad, CudaText)

Tags: extract, pspad

I need extract text between symbols **'$$$** and **'**

How to do it?

Example:

*dva_popup(identifier: 'importAs', label: **'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/kResMediaCoreUIImportAs=Import As: '**, bindRight:'true')
                    {
                        dva_popup_item(name: **'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/MergeAllLayers=Merge All Layers'**);
                        dva_popup_item(name: **'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/MergedLayers=Merged Layers'**);
                        dva_popup_item(name: **'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/Footage=Individual Layers'**);
                        dva_popup_item(name: **'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/Sequence=Sequence'**);}
                {
        dva_listbox(identifier: 'layerSelection', useCheckboxes: 'true', direction:'vertical', minWidth: 250, minHeight: 150, bindRight:'true', bindBottom:'true');
                dva_arrangement(arrangementType: 'row', horizontalSpacing: 6, verticalSpacing: 6)}*

Result:

'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/kResMediaCoreUIImportAs=Import As: '

'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/MergeAllLayers=Merge All Layers'

'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/MergedLayers=Merged Layers'

'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/Footage=Individual Layers'

'$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/Sequence=Sequence'

Result may be without the **'** symbol too

I'm working in PS-Pad and CudaText

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

regex

1. replace

   '(\$\$\$)

with

```
\r\n\1
```

2. replace

   '.*$

with

(nul) just leave replace with area without anything (not even blank or space)

output

```
    dva_popup(identifier: 
$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/kResMediaCoreUIImportAs=Import As: 
$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/MergeAllLayers=Merge All Layers
$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/MergedLayers=Merged Layers
$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/Footage=Individual Layers
$$$/MediaCoreUI/PhotoshopImporterPrefs/Sequence=Sequence
```

A stray first line remains, delete that manually.

as ' is coming multiple times in the line apart from these two occurences, removing it will make regex less complex and quick.

I have tried it in notepad++, Hope regex works the same in your editor also.